# WSO2 API Manager and OAuth 1a signature verification

Tags: rest, oauth, wso2, wso2-api-manager, appdirect

I am trying to integrate with a commerce platform called AppDirect.  Every request AppDirect sends to my REST API service will be signed with an OAuth 1a signature.  AppDirect does not use OAuth access tokens.  Also, AppDirect provides the OAuth consumer key and consumer secret.  See  - https://docs.appdirect.com/developer/apis/billing-api-guide/oauth-credentials#validating-requests-from-appdirect for details.

I want to use WSO2 API Manager to perform signature verification, but I cannot find a way to enter AppDirect's key and secret into API Manager for signature verification.   Is there a way to do this without writing custom code?

Comment: Were you able to make it work with WSO2 API Manager ?

Comment: No, I was not able to figure out a way to do this.